# How to check for changes to the program code while I am running it

Tags: c++, authorization, reverse-engineering

Hello fellow developers,

assume I had a program that required authorization granted to him by a server over the network. Obviously, at some point within my code there would be something along the lines of:

```
if (serverResponse == expectedResponse){
    //Continue as the authorized user
}
```

This system has a very, very unlikely weakness. If anybody were to actually modify the executable file and change the code of that `if` (which I assume to be some sort of branching instruction) to code, that always branches to the true-case. Is there a way to detect such a modification from within my program?

To me this sounds like a psychologist checking his own sanity. If this is not possible, how would such a thing be done? How does software like Punkbuster check for manipulation of game code?

I guess it might be very relevant that this program of mine is written in C++ and compiled with the GCC compiler.

Comment: Actually it's not that unlikely, me and some friends did it all the time on a game.

Comment: You cannot fully secure any code that runs on the client.

Comment: If the user can alter one part of the program what's to stop them from changing the change-checking part as well?

Comment: Theoretically, there is no way you are sure your program was not modified. But you may make it hard by encrypting your program, and decoding it during running. Or having a special windows service checking the file integrity.

Comment: The only real way to avoid this is to run all "trusted" code on the server only (and of course make sure your server is secure).  (you could also run the same code in parallel on the client, but you'd need to double-check any results sent by the client on the server side to make sure they were legit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is not to rely on a simple if statement. As you say that is easily circumvented by someone who can reverse engineer your code. Instead you should use the value returned from the server for some vital function of your program. For instance the response from the server could be used as a key to decrypt some vital data on the client. That would be much harder for a reverse engineer to circumvent.

Comment: I have thought about it. In fact, my program will rely on a database that will be constantly maintained by the server. In addition to that, I have thought about what is mentioned in this article: http://sigpipe.macromates.com/2004/09/05/using-openssl-for-license-keys/. If I encrypt and send the database only to authorized clients, my program should be pretty safe. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to take the address of the function and obtain the CRC of the memory at that address. This isn't very flexible however, because you have to either calculate the size of the function every time you modify it, or use a disassembler library like the magnificent and free [BEAEngine](http://www.beaengine.org/) to dynamically calculate it. But then there's the possibility of the reverse engineer modifying your CRC code. Or the checksum it's checking it against. They can also modify the server's response before your program gets it and change it to the `expectedResponse`. So you really can't win.

There are also softwares such as the free [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) which will pack your executable (and obfuscate it if you tell them to) and make it very difficult for people to read and modify to achieve the correct result they are going for.

However, if someone has enough time and skill, there's really nothing you can do. As we used to say, the client always wins; all you can do is make the game more difficult.